# can I use CSV.foreach to delete a row in a CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv, delete-row

I need to delete rows out of a CSV when it does not match a criteria, is it possible to use CSV.foreach to delete rows out of a CSV file?

here is a snippet of my code

```
require 'csv'

path = 'C:\Users\ALilland\Documents\macros\automated-jobs-change-orders-report\jobs-and-change-orders.csv'

CSV.foreach(path, :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8') do |row|
  sp = row[1]
  next if sp == 'BD' || sp == 'RR' || sp == 'FU' || sp == 'JH' || sp == 'MN' ||
          sp == 'DR' || sp == 'MT' || sp == 'MM' || sp == 'GS' || sp == 'DM' ||
          sp == 'JN'

  row[1].delete # need something like this
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`CSV.foreach` is read-only. If you want to write to the csv file, you'll need something like

```
CSV.open(path+"~", "wb") do |out_csv|
  CSV.foreach(path) do |in_csv|
    out << in_csv if row_should_be_included?(in_csv)
  end
end

File.delete(path)
File.rename(path+"~",path)
```

Comment: The call to `CSV.open(path, "wb")` will most likely open the file for writing immediately, causing its contents to be erased.  You better use a different path for the `CSV.open` and `CSV.foreach`, so that the output filename is different from the input filename.  You can delete the input file and rename the output file later after it has been fully written to.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Oh my gosh, thank you. Bad mistake, edited now.

Comment: Should the second last line use `#delete`? See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-delete